# Getting error on shutdown of simple Micronaut CLI data application

Tags: java, micronaut, dbcp

I have just developed a small micronaut CLI app to explore Micronaut jdbc and sql features. Following are the dependencies,

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("info.picocli:picocli-codegen:4.2.0")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    implementation("info.picocli:picocli")
    implementation("io.micronaut.picocli:micronaut-picocli")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-dbcp")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-jdbc")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    runtimeOnly("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    testImplementation(platform("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.14.3"))
    testRuntimeOnly("org.testcontainers:mssqlserver")
}
```

The app runs fine but on exiting it fails with following error,

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionAwareDataSource$DataSourceProxy cannot be cast to class io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.dbcp.DatasourceConfiguration (io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionAwareDataSource$DataSourceProxy and io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.dbcp.DatasourceConfiguration are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
            at io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.dbcp.$DatasourceConfigurationDefinition.dispose(Unknown Source)
            at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate$ProxyDisposableBeanDefinition.dispose(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:257)
            at io.micronaut.inject.DisposableBeanDefinition.dispose(DisposableBeanDefinition.java:41)
            at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.stop(DefaultBeanContext.java:290)
            at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.stop(DefaultApplicationContext.java:171)
            at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.stop(DefaultApplicationContext.java:49)
            at io.micronaut.context.LifeCycle.close(LifeCycle.java:61)
            at io.micronaut.configuration.picocli.PicocliRunner.run(PicocliRunner.java:115)
            at mnsdb.MnsdbCommand.main(MnsdbCommand.java:21)
```

I tried to go through the annotation based generated code in `$DatasourceConfigurationDefinition`
and found that in dispose method there is a checkcast instruction (check line no. 1)

```
  public java.lang.Object dispose(io.micronaut.context.BeanResolutionContext arg0, io.micronaut.context.BeanContext arg1, java.lang.Object arg2);
     0  aload_3 [arg2]
     1  checkcast io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.dbcp.DatasourceConfiguration [9]
     4  astore 4
     6  aload_0 [this]
     7  aload_1 [arg0]
     8  aload_2 [arg1]
     9  checkcast io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext [593]
    12  aload_3 [arg2]
    13  invokespecial io.micronaut.context.AbstractParametrizedBeanDefinition.preDestroy(io.micronaut.context.BeanResolutionContext, io.micronaut.context.BeanContext, java.lang.Object) : java.lang.Object [612]
    16  aload 4
    18  invokevirtual io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.dbcp.DatasourceConfiguration.preDestroy() : void [618]
    21  aload 4
    23  areturn
```

So apparently micronaut is replacing the instance of `io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.dbcp.DatasourceConfiguration` with `TransactionAwareDataSource$DataSourceProxy` when the context is intialized but while disposing the beans .. it fails because proxy could not be casted the instance which it has wrapped.

This looks like a very simple error (which could have been caught by micronaut's automation test suite) so I feel it must be happening due to some misconfiguration in dependencies.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dbcp, when I used Hikari (jdbc-hikari) the problem went away.

So looks like some issue with jdbc-dbcp data source implementation.